# How to create a new virtualenv with pipenv in a subdirectory of a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I have this directory structure:

```
code/
├── some_script.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── subdirectory/
    └── script_to_run.py
```

Inside `subdirectory/` directory, I want to run `script_to_run.py`, however when I `pipenv run python3 script_to_run.py` I get the problem that pipenv assumes I'm in the `code/` directory, rather than the `subdirectory/` directory.

How do I generate a new virtualenv for `subdirectory/` with pipenv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd subdirectory
touch Pipfile
pipenv run python3 script_to_run.py
```

This will generate a new virtualenv for this subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

For newbies like me:

Create an empty file (fill with 1 space if using nano) named "Pipfile" (must with capital "P").

Then just run "pipenv shell" in the subfolder. It should create a new env in the subfolder.

Comment: That's exactly what `touch Pipfile` does...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `pipenv run subdirectory/script_to_run.py`

Comment: With this route you won’t get a new virtualenv for that directory.

Comment: Yes, but i'm assuming OP wants to use the same venv he has in the root folder to run the script in the subfolder. If he needs a different one, then your answer is correct.

Comment: Yep! 
Relying on ”How do I generate a new virtualenv for `subdirectory/` with pipenv?”